# Unity android Native Camera as WebcamTexture

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, camera

Can someone help me about to use the Native Camera of Android in Unity the same way we use WebcamTexture? I want the "camera preview image" in Unity as a texture2d or texture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it once using https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/graphicsdemos as starting point. You are going to be interested in the **RenderingPlugin.cpp**.

Back in the day I had to use code in Java as bridge to Android NDK since it was not possible to plug an ImageReader in the camera feed on the C level due to security reasons.

It looks like things got updated and it might be possible to simplify the architecture by using https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/camera.

Hope this helps.

ps-> In case you want to do a code walkthrough I put together an end-to-end demo here https://github.com/robsondepaula/unity-android-native-camera